# Iframe contents are lost after opening a jquery modal dialog

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, iframe

I have an iframe. It was inside a modal. See code below:

```
<iframe id="edit-text-modal-value_ifr" src='javascript:""' frameborder="0" allowtransparency="true" title="Rich Text AreaPress ALT-F10 for toolbar. Press ALT-0 for help" style="width: 100%; height: 100px; display: block;">
   #document
   <!DOCTYPE>
   <html>
        <head xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
           <style id="mceDefaultStyles" type="text/css">
               .mceResizeHandle {
                   position: absolute;
                   border: 1px solid black;
                   background: #FFF;
                   width: 5px;
                   height: 5px;
                   z-index: 10000
               }
               .mceResizeHandle:hover {
                   background: #000
               }
               img[data-mce-selected] {
                   outline: 1px solid black
               }
               img.mceClonedResizable,
               table.mceClonedResizable {
                   position: absolute;
                   outline: 1px dashed black;
                   opacity: .5;
                   z-index: 10000
               }
           </style>
           <base href="http://localhost/drupal-7.34/">
           <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
           <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="http://localhost/drupal-7.34/sites/all/libraries/tinymce/jscripts/tiny_mce/themes/advanced/skins/default/content.css">
           <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="http://localhost/drupal-7.34/themes/bartik/css/layout.css">
           <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="http://localhost/drupal-7.34/themes/bartik/css/style.css">
           <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="http://localhost/drupal-7.34/themes/bartik/css/colors.css">
       </head>

       <body id="tinymce" class="mceContentBody " onload="window.parent.tinyMCE.get('edit-text-modal-value').onLoad.dispatch();" contenteditable="true" spellcheck="false" dir="ltr">
           <p>
               <br data-mce-bogus="1">
           </p>
       </body>  
   </html>
</iframe>
```

When I open another modal using jquery modal plugin, the iframe's content was lost. Why? How will I prevent it?

Jquery Code:

```
jQuery('#myid_templates_editor_insertf_field_modal').dialog('open');
```

My new Iframe's code :

```
<iframe id="edit-text-modal-value_ifr" src='javascript:""' frameborder="0" allowtransparency="true" title="Rich Text AreaPress ALT-F10 for toolbar. Press ALT-0 for help" style="width: 100%; height: 100px; display: block;">
    #document
    <html>
        <head></head>
        <body></body>
    </html>
</iframe>
```

Comment: seem to have left out a lot of relevant information like how tinymce is being initialized and on what elements  and how the dialogs are initialized. The insides of the iframes really aren't relevant here...it's how they are being generated that is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    $('.the-modal').bind('shown', function() {
       tinyMCE.execCommand('mceAddControl', false, 'mce-<?=$reply["id"]?>');
    });

    $('.the-modal').bind('hide', function() {
        tinyMCE.execCommand('mceRemoveControl', false, 'mce-<?=$reply["id"]?>');
    });
</script>
```

It was a bug and I found a solution [here](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/549).

Answer (score 0):

well,ofcourse it will gone.because modal data is created dynimacally.so what you can do when you are calling another mode copy iframe object into another object-like

```
var tmp=document.getelememntbyid('iframeid');
```

and declare tmp variable gloabaly and use it again when you want.